# Incrontab / Incron on Cygwin

Tags: files, cygwin, incron

Does anyone please know if it is possible to install incron/incrontab within Cygwin?

I've had a look and the package does not appear on the cygwin website, I wondered if anyone had tried, knew of any method or had any success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`incron` relies on `inotify`, which isn’t emulated by Cygwin. To run on Windows it would have to be re-written using equivalent Windows functionality; see [Is there anything like inotify on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows) for details. The answers to that question give links to various Windows tools which may provide the functionality you’re looking for.